# Build number of previous build number

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a Jenkins pipeline job which will check the status of previous before it trigger the execution. But I am not able to find the url to previous build number. I tried constructing url using BUILD_NUMBER-1 option but not working because BUILD_NUMBER is not a integer. Could someone help me to find the url to previous build ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the `currentBuild` global variable. You can see all global variables at http://jenkins-url/pipeline-syntax/globals.

The `number` can be retrieved from it. You can see all of the whitelisted calls on [`RunWrapper`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-support-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.java).

> **number**
>
> build number (integer)

So, in your pipeline you could do `currentBuild.number`.

If there is a previous build, you could also use `previousBuild` and use `currentBuild.previousBuild.number`. Keep in mind that `previousBuild` can be `null`.